# Can't connect PostgreSQL database to FastAPI

Tags: python, postgresql, fastapi

So, hi. Everything works with SQLite, but when I try to add PostgreSQL according to the user's guide on FastAPI, nothing works and I get:

`sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) invalid dsn: invalid connection option "check_same_thread"`

My `database.py` is:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

#SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./sql_app.db"
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://user:password@postgresserver/db"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`check_same_thread` is an argument specific to sqlite. As you've specified a Postgres URL, you can remove that argument and you should have no issue creating an engine.

i.e:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://user:password@postgresserver/db"

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Unfortunately still doesn't work

Comment: Now it is ```sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution```

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy needs a little bit different dsn. To make sure, use PostgresDsn from pydantic.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from pydantic import PostgresDsn

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = PostgresDsn.build(
    scheme="postgresql",
    user="POSTGRES_USER",
    password="POSTGRES_PASSWORD",
    host="POSTGRES_SERVER",
    path=f"/{'POSTGRES_DB' or ''}",
)
engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI,
    pool_pre_ping=True,
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(
    autocommit=False,
    autoflush=False,
    bind=engine
)
try:
    db = SessionLocal()
    db.execute("SELECT 1")
except Exception as e:
    raise e
```